# Bootstrap 4: Disable refresh whole page when page of GridView is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

Currently I created GridView and can click change page as below.
However, I want to disable refresh whole page when page of GridView is changed.
Could you please help to suggest me?
.aspx

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView1_OnPageIndexChanging" CssClass="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive-sm small">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
    dataTable1.Columns.Add("Column 1");
    dataTable1.Columns.Add("Column 2");
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("1", "1");
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("2", "2");
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("3", "3");
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("4", "4");
    gridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;
    gridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void gridView1_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Output
[image: Bootstrap 4: Disable refresh whole page when page of GridView is changed]

Comment: Why is this marked [tag:bootstrap-4]?

Comment: @Amadan, Because I'm using bootstrap 4, CssClass="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive-sm small", and I want solution in responsive too.

Comment: Use `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` . It prevents reloading of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'have missed this...

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="SC1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView1_OnPageIndexChanging" CssClass="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive-sm small">
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Note:- you have to add Update Panel

if your problem is still not solved...then refer this link

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-and-Sorting-without-PostBack-Refresh-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot 'DISABLE' page reloads in standard browsers, you can just add a "TIP" for the user to see who can choose not to reload the page, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Window/onunload